# Many to many relation entries not added by .add() method in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many

I am having a problem regarding adding entry to a many to many relation field. I have the models as follows

```py
class Address(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)', blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Country')
    state = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=STATE_CHOICES,
        verbose_name='State',
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    ...

class Volunteer(models.Model):
    userID = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='id', primary_key=True, related_name='volunteer')
    identificationNumber = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Identification   Number')
    currentAddress = models.ManyToManyField(Address, related_name='volunteerCurrentAddress', verbose_name='Current Address', blank=False)
    permanentAddress = models.ManyToManyField(Address, related_name='volunteerPermanentAddress', verbose_name='Permanent Address', blank=False)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.userID.username
        super(Volunteer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class TemporaryVolunteer(Volunteer):
    pass
```

And in the views, I get both the `currentAddress` and `permanentAddress` fields as a `ManyToManyRelatedManager`. They are `temporaryVolunteer.currentAddress` and `temporaryVolunteer.permanentAddress`. I use these to create a new Volunteer instance as

```py
volunteer = Volunteer(...)
volunteer.save()
volunteer.currentAddress.add(temporaryVolunteer.currentAddress.all()[0])
volunteer.permanentAddress.add(temporaryVolunteer.permanentAddress.all()[0])
volunteer.save()
```

But when I do `print(volunteer.currentAddress.all())` or `print(volunteer.permanentAddress.all())`, it returns an empty queryset. I also checked the admin site for confirmation and there are no entries of address on the volunteer instance. 
Is there any way the entries can be added with this approach?

Comment: are you sure that temporaryVolunteer has data? or did you create instance of this class before adding this to volunteer instance?

Comment: @Maede The `temporaryVolunteer` did have data. As you mentioned about creating an instance of that class before adding to the volunteer, I remembered about the way django handles many to many relations if there is a duplicate and it solved my problem. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the design of the database. I had used a new class `TemporaryVolunteer` in order to store unverified accounts and later moved to the `Volunteer` class after they were verfied. As I had inherited `TemporaryVolunteer` from `Volunteer` class, the way Django handles Many to many relationships without making duplicates (Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) led to the problem of no entries being added in the corresponding `Volunteer` class.

Initially, I checked this by copying all the members of `Volunteer` to `TemporaryVolunteer`. After verifying that it worked, I changed the database design as this is a bad approach and kept a boolean value `isVerified` in the `Volunteer` class and removed the `TemporaryVolunteer` class entirely.